# Why won't my PhP form send the Data to my email?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am new to coding and Im trying to find out why my php code will not send my form data to my email if someone could direct me to somewhere Where i could learn how to get it to send or give me some tips I would really appreciate it.

HTML: [UPDATED]

```
    <a id="faq-scroll"></a>
    <section id="faq">
            <div class="row pad-large">
<div class="row">
            <div class="large-8 large-centered columns pad-bottom-small">
                <div id="faq-form" class="text-center">
                    <form method = "POST" action = "mail.php">
                        <input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" />
                        <input id="middleinitial" type="text" placeholder="Middle Name" name="middleinitial" />
                        <input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" />
                        <input id="email2" type="text" placeholder="E-mail address" name="email2" />
                        <select id="form_dob_month" name="dob_month">
                        <option value="-">Date</option>
                        <option value="1">January</option>
                        <option value="2">Febuary</option>
                        <option value="3">March</option>
                        <option value="4">April</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">June</option>
                        <option value="7">July</option>
                        <option value="8">August</option>
                        <option value="9">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
                        <select id="form_dob_day" name="dob_day">
                        <option value="-">Of</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
                        <select id="form_dob_year" name="dob_year">
                        <option value="-">Birth</option>
                        <option value="2011">2011</option>
                        <option value="2010">2010</option>
                        <option value="2009">2009</option>
                        <option value="2008">2008</option>
                        <option value="2007">2007</option>
                        <option value="2006">2006</option>
                        <option value="2005">2005</option>
                        <option value="2004">2004</option>
                        <option value="2003">2003</option>
                        <option value="2002">2002</option>
                        <option value="2001">2001</option>
                        <option value="2000">2000</option>
                        <option value="1999">1999</option>
                        <option value="1998">1998</option>
                        <option value="1997">1997</option>
                        <option value="1996">1996</option>
                        <option value="1995">1995</option>
                        <option value="1994">1994</option>
                        <option value="1993">1993</option>
                        <option value="1992">1992</option>
                        <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        <option value="1990">1990</option>
                        <option value="1989">1989</option>
                        <option value="1988">1988</option>
                        <option value="1987">1987</option>
                        <option value="1986">1986</option>
                        <option value="1985">1985</option>
                        <option value="1984">1984</option>
                        <option value="1983">1983</option>
                        <option value="1982">1982</option>
                        <option value="1981">1981</option>
                        <option value="1980">1980</option>
                        <option value="1979">1979</option>
                        <option value="1978">1978</option>
                        <option value="1977">1977</option>
                        <option value="1976">1976</option>
                        <option value="1975">1975</option>
                        <option value="1974">1974</option>
                        <option value="1973">1973</option>
                        <option value="1972">1972</option>
                        <option value="1971">1971</option>
                        <option value="1970">1970</option>
                        <option value="1969">1969</option>
                        <option value="1968">1968</option>
                        <option value="1967">1967</option>
                        <option value="1966">1966</option>
                        <option value="1965">1965</option>
                        <option value="1964">1964</option>
                        <option value="1963">1963</option>
                        <option value="1962">1962</option>
                        <option value="1961">1961</option>
                        <option value="1960">1960</option>
                        <option value="1959">1959</option>
                        <option value="1958">1958</option>
                        <option value="1957">1957</option>
                        <option value="1956">1956</option>
                        <option value="1955">1955</option>
                        <option value="1954">1954</option>
                        <option value="1953">1953</option>
                        <option value="1952">1952</option>
                        <option value="1951">1951</option>
                        <option value="1950">1950</option>
                        <option value="1949">1949</option>
                        <option value="1948">1948</option>
                        <option value="1947">1947</option>
                        <option value="1946">1946</option>
                        <option value="1945">1945</option>
                        <option value="1944">1944</option>
                        <option value="1943">1943</option>
                        <option value="1942">1942</option>
                        <option value="1941">1941</option>
                        <option value="1940">1940</option>
                        <option value="1939">1939</option>
                        <option value="1938">1938</option>
                        <option value="1937">1937</option>
                        <option value="1936">1936</option>
                        <option value="1935">1935</option>
                        <option value="1934">1934</option>
                        <option value="1933">1933</option>
                        <option value="1932">1932</option>
                        <option value="1931">1931</option>
                        <option value="1930">1930</option>
                        <option value="1929">1929</option>
                        <option value="1928">1928</option>
                        <option value="1927">1927</option>
                        <option value="1926">1926</option>
                        <option value="1925">1925</option>
                        <option value="1924">1924</option>
                        <option value="1923">1923</option>
                        <option value="1922">1922</option>
                        <option value="1921">1921</option>
                        <option value="1920">1920</option>
                        <option value="1919">1919</option>
                        <option value="1918">1918</option>
                        <option value="1917">1917</option>
                        <option value="1916">1916</option>
                        <option value="1915">1915</option>
                        <option value="1914">1914</option>
                        <option value="1913">1913</option>
                        <option value="1912">1912</option>
                        <option value="1911">1911</option>
                        <option value="1910">1910</option>
        </select>               
                        <input id="social" type="text" placeholder="Social Security #" name="socialsecurity#" />
                        <input id="Driver" type="text" placeholder="Driver License #" name="driverlicense#" />
                        <input id="cellphone" type="text" placeholder="Cell Phone" name="cellphone" />
                        <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Street Address" name="streetaddress" />
                        <input id="zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" name="zipcode" />
                        <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City" name="city" />
                        <select id="form_state" name="State">
                        <option value="-">State</option>
                        <option value="1">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="2">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="3">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="5">California</option>
                        <option value="6">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="7">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="8">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="9">Florida</option>
                        <option value="10">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="11">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="12">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="13">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="14">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="15">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="16">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="17">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="18">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="19">Maine</option>
                        <option value="20">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="21">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="22">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="23">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="24">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="25">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="26">Montana</option>
                        <option value="27">Nebraska </option>
                        <option value="28">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="29">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="30">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="31">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="32">New York</option>
                        <option value="33">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="34">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="35">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="36">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="37">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="38">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="39">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="40">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="41">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="42">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="43">Texas</option>
                        <option value="44">Utah</option>
                        <option value="45">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="46">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="47">Washington</option>
                        <option value="48">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="49">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="50">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>   
                        <input id="timeataddress" type="text" placeholder="Time at Present Address" name="timeatpresentaddress" />
                        <input id="rent" type="text" placeholder="Monthly Rent/Mortgage Payment" name="monthlyrent/mortgagepayment" />
                        <input id="jobtitle" type="text" placeholder="Present Job Title" name="presentjobtitle" />
                        <input id="employer" type="text" placeholder="Present Employer" name="presentemployer" />
                        <input id="employerphone" type="text" placeholder="Employer Phone Number" name="employerphonenumber" />
                        <input id="jobtime" type="text" placeholder="Time at Present Job" name="timeatpresentjob" />
                        <input id="grossincome" type="text" placeholder="Monthly Gross Income" name="monthlygrossincome" />
                        <input id="question-ask" type="submit" value="SUBMIT YOUR APPLICATION" class="btn btn-green" />
                        <div id="details-error"><i class="icon-alert">&nbsp;</i>Please enter all details correctly</div>
                        <div id="form-sent"><i class="icon-check">&nbsp;</i>Message sent, thanks for your enquiry</div>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

PHP: [UPDATED]

```
<?php
    if ($_POST) {
        $firstname  = $_POST['firstname'];
        $middleinitial = $_POST['middleinitial'];
        $lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email2  = $_POST['emailaddress'];
        $form_dob_month  = $_POST['dob_month'];
        $form_dob_day  = $_POST['dob_day'];
        $form_dob_year  = $_POST['dob_year'];
        $social  = $_POST['socialsecurity#'];
        $Driver  = $_POST['driverlicense#'];
        $cellphone  = $_POST['cellphone'];
        $address  = $_POST['streetaddress'];
        $zip  = $_POST['zipcode'];
        $city  = $_POST['city'];
        $form_state  = $_POST['state'];
        $timeataddress  = $_POST['timeatpresentaddress'];
        $rent  = $_POST['monthlyrent/mortgagepayment'];
        $jobtitle  = $_POST['presentjobtitle'];
        $employer  = $_POST['presentemployer'];
        $employerphone  = $_POST['employerphonenumber'];
        $jobtime  = $_POST['timeatpresentjob'];
        $grossincome  = $_POST['monthlygrossincome'];
     }   


$body = $email2.' has submitted some data';
        mail("iamdrivingleads@yahoo.com", "email enquiry", $body);


?>
```

Comment: change `method="_POST"` to `method="post"`

Comment: After that, I think you will need to pass it some header information otherwise your email will probably be junked.  If you google it, you will find various sites that will tell you what header information you need to avoid this from happening.

Comment: Eh, FYI, your years are all screwed up (the last one is `<option value="1965">1910</option>`).

Answer (score 1):

you have multi errors:

1. You should use attribute [name] in all HTML elements

example:

```
<input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" />
```

2. You didn't use data POST values in you email body
3. You have an error in mail function you must remove last [,] from parameters

   ```
   mail("iamdrivingleads@yahoo.com", "email enquiry", $body);
   ```

Good luck

Comment: I have updated my code @basem if you could take another look and tell me if you see any errors I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think your code is right now, But you will not your form data because you just use the var [$email2] in you $body
try to include all vars in your message

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP form won't send the form data to your email because:

1. Your form is using the method `_POST` instead of `POST`
2. The `POST'ed` variables you are  accessing in your PHP script `$_POST[...]` should be identified with `name` attribute (instead of the `id` attribute you used) in your `HTML` script

As a side-note, I believe this code is not for production server, because it still lacks some conventional mail sending sanity checks, such as headers that will decrease the chances of your message ending up in spam folder, etc.

Comment: hi @emmanuel I have made the changes and corrections that you said if you could point out anymore tips as I have updated the code thank you very much.